# How to get values from Adaptive Cards Submit Action in LUIS | C#

Tags: c#, submit, botframework, azure-language-understanding, adaptive-cards

I am currently working on a LUIS bot that creates projects in VSTS.
Right now you just write the name to the bot like "Create Projekt abcd" and it creates the project for you.
I wanted to make it look better by adding Adaptive Cards for the input, but when I press the submit button it just says to the Bot Code has an error.
I did some research and the problem seems that the LUIS bot does not know how to handle the object that is returned as a message.

Adaptive Card: `

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AdaptiveCards;
using AdaptiveCards.Rendering;
using AdaptiveCards.Rendering.Html;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;

namespace LuisBot.Dialogs
{
public class ProjektInputCard
{


    public static Attachment GetCard(String pName)
    {
        String projektname = pName;
        if (projektname.Equals("(Name not found)"))
        {
            projektname = "";
        }

        AdaptiveCard Card = new AdaptiveCard() 
        {
            Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
            {
                new AdaptiveContainer()
                {
                    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                    {
                        new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                        {
                            Text = "Projekterstellung",
                            Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                            Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Large
                        },
                        new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                        {
                            Text = "Projektname:",
                            Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                            Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Default
                        },
                        new AdaptiveTextInput()
                        {
                            Type = "Input.Text",
                            Id = "ID_projekt",
                            Value = projektname
                        },
                        new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                        {
                            Text = "Beschreibung:",
                            Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                            Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Default
                        },

                        new AdaptiveTextInput()
                        {
                            Type = "Input.Text",
                            Id = "ID_description",
                            Value = "",
                            IsMultiline = true
                        }
                    }


                }



            }


        };

        Card.Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>()
        {
            new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
            {
                Type = "Action.Submit",
                Title = "Erstellen"
            }
        };

        Attachment Attach = new Attachment() 
        {
            ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
            Content = Card
        };

        return Attach;
    }
}
}`
```

Methode that calls the Card: `

```
private async Task Test(IDialogContext context)
     {

        var createprompt = context.MakeMessage();
    createprompt.Attachments.Add(ProjektInputCard.GetCard(GetProjectName()));
        await context.PostAsync(createprompt);

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }`
```

The MessageReceived Methode:

```
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;
        InputValues data;
        if (message.Value != null)
        {
            // Got an Action Submit
            dynamic value = message.Value;
            string submitType = value.Type.ToString();
            if (value != null)
            {
                data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputValues>(submitType);
                _projectname = data.Name;
                _description = data.Description;
                await this.ShowLuisResult(context);

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ceepert,
Instead of trying to do this all in the same class (I think that's what I'm seeing in your code), what you want to do is separate you adaptive card parts and luis parts into separate dialogs. Your initial dialog would be a regular IDialog<> implementation.

Collect the data from your input, create a new message with the data from the adaptive card as the Text property of the message and do call context.Forward to send the new message to your luis dialog. 
It's not clear from your code which input from the AdaptiveCard is going to be used by Luis to determine the user's intent so I've assumed '_projectname' for my example

If there is additional data beyond the Text, you can pass it in as parameters to the Luis dialog constructor.

```
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;

    if (message.Value != null)
    {
        //reroute the user back to your card with an additional message to 
        //put response in the provided fields.
        return;
    }

    InputValues data;
    if (message.Value != null)
    {
        // Got an Action Submit
        dynamic value = message.Value;
        string submitType = value.Type.ToString();
        if (value != null)
        {
            data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InputValues>(submitType);
            _projectname = data.Name;
            _description = data.Description;

            IMessageActivity msg = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            msg.TextFormat = "text";
            msg.Text = _projectname;

            await context.Forward(new MyLuisDialog(), ResumeAfterLuisDialog, msg, CancellationToken.None);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and I am gonna test what you wrote, but I dont want the data from the AdaptiveCard to be used by LUIS. The User writes a Projektname and Description and with that a VSTS should be created. The Problem I am facing is a) The dialog is not waiting for the card to be filled and the "Submit" button pressed, so you could just write something else to the bot when the card is shown and b) I dont know how to get the values out of it.(but that may be fixed with what you wrote, need to test that first)

Comment: Oh and "message.CreateMessage();" does not exist, I already saw that a few times, but have no idea where that "message" var comes from, all I can do is "context.MakeMessage();"

Comment: Couple of things. First, I corrected my code example. Sorry for the confusion!.  Second, ok, when you 'submit' an adaptive card the data comes in via message.Value, when the user just writes something else to the bot, this comes is via message.Text. When they do that, you do not get anything from the card. This is a common error check you should be doing. What I typically do is check at the beginning of the method for message.text and re-display the card with an additional text block saying something like 'Please type you responses in the fields provided'